# Why php crashes when writing and opening a file?

Tags: php

how the php is making error while opening and writing to the file.

```
function makeImage() {
    $encoded_string = $_POST['encoded_string'];
    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);
    $path = "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\apbclt.com\httpdocs\php\logo".$_POST['company_name'];
    $file = fopen($path, 'wb');
    $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
    fclose($file);
    if($is_written > 0) {
        global $mysqli;
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Companies (logo) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $path);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        }else{
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the error

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(C:\Inetpubhosts\apbclt.com\httpdocs\php\logo): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\apbclt.com\httpdocs\php\create_company.php on line 54
PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\apbclt.com\httpdocs\php\create_company.php on line 55
PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\apbclt.com\httpdocs\php\create_company.php on line 56
```

I searched SO but no answer to my case.

**Update ::**

when I changed the \v to \v like the first answer i got the following error.

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\apbclt.com\httpdocs\php\logo): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\apbclt.com\httpdocs\php\create_company.php on line 54
PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\apbclt.com\httpdocs\php\create_company.php on line 55
PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\apbclt.com\httpdocs\php\create_company.php on line 56
```

Comment: This is most likely a file permissions issue.  Does the web server have permission to write to the directory the file is in?

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved the issue instead of using the full file path I just used the path by going back a folder `..\logo`